# Is overloading a method without throwing an exception an antipattern?

Tags: oop, anti-patterns

We are currently designing an API for storing settings and we are considering having these two types of methods:

```
public Object getSetting(String key) {
    // return null if key does not exist
}

public Object getSettingExc(String key) {
    // throw a runtime exception if key does not exist
}
```

Somehow I feel that this just isn't right, but I can't think of any disadvantages except for doubling the number of functions in the API and perhaps decreased code readability (if I know the setting MUST exist, I think I should throw an exception explicitly rather than relying on the get method).

What are your opinions on this?

Comment: Are both methods really necessary?  It seems that the logic of what to do if a key doesn't exist should be determined by this object, not by the consuming code.  Besides, this looks like Java, which means that `getSetting` can simply advertise the potential exception and let consuming code handling it (or not handle it) accordingly.  I see no need for separate methods here.

Comment: I think the two methods are not necessary. We'd probably be ok with just the one not throwing an exception. I'm just trying to gather arguments to persuade other guys in my team.

Comment: Can first method return null ever?

Comment: any reason why generics can't be used instead of returning Object?  You'll eliminate the cast, which is always nice.  If it is expected that getting a setting will return null, then sure, return null.  If not, then I think asserting is the correct way to go.  Unless you're putting it out for public use, in which case a exceptions are probably needed.

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions are for *exceptional* occurrences, when the code cannot continue to function according to its advertised function.

Requesting a setting that isn't set is hardly exception-worthy. If "you" (i.e. the *calling* code) "know" that setting "must" exist, call `getSetting()`, check the return value for null, and **then** throw an exception yourself out of the knowledge that it should have been there. Add a meaningful message about what setting in which context wasn't found. (This is something only the *caller* knows.)

Don't delegate the throwing of the exception to code that *doesn't* know the context of the query *or* that the setting should *be* there, and needs to be told explicitly (by getting called under a different name). Also, `getSettingExc()` will most likely be only a null-check-and-throw wrapper around `getSetting()` anyway, so why not do it at a point where you can make the exception message so much more helpful?

IMHO. (And this is the point where I realize I should have voted-to-close instead of writing an answer...)

Answer (score 1):

This is introducing a weird kind of coupling between the object structure and the potential error conditions.  Regarding your comment:

> I'm just trying to gather arguments to persuade other guys in my team.

The onus should be on the *proponent* of this design to justify it, not on you to justify against it.  Nobody else uses this in any design I've ever seen.

This *does* however remind me of another design that *maybe* is what your team intended?  Consider these two methods:

```
public Object getSetting(String key) {
    // return the setting or throw an exception
}

public Object getSettingOrDefault(String key) {
    // return the setting or a pre-determined default
}
```

This aligns the methods more with the functionality than with the error conditions.  `getSetting()` can advertise that it might throw an exception, whereas `getSettingOrDefault()` can advertise that it will default to a specific value if none can be found in the settings.

If Java has optional parameters or something akin to that, `getSettingOrDefault()` might even accept as an argument a default to use in the event of no such setting.  That might get a little kludgy for consuming code though, just sort of thinking out loud on that one.

Either way, the API should reflect the *functionality* and not the *error conditions*.  *Ideally* there should be only one method, but if there's a noticeable need to differentiate between a method that throws and a method that doesn't (and I could certainly see that being the case in a language with checked exceptions), those two should align with the functionality rather than with the exception.

Comment: Thanks you mentioned some valid points there. And no, the intention was not to return default values, but to terminate the execution when a crucial setting is not found.

Comment: @Jardo: It's a similar pattern at least.  In any event, if a crucial setting isn't found then that sounds like exactly when to use an exception because it means the application can't continue running as intended.  Let this internal component throw the exception, let the consuming application handle the exception (such as by informing the user that an operation couldn't be completed because of a configuration problem).

Comment: Yes but the problem is, that not all settings are crucial and as DevSolar pointed out in his answer, only the caller knows if the setting is crucial, so he should be responsible for throwing the exception.

Comment: @Jardo: Then either throw an exception and let the calling code handle it, or return an empty value and let the calling code examine it.  Both cases involve the same logical paths, it's just a semantic question of whether or not a missing setting is an "exceptional" case or not.  If it isn't, return an empty value.  If it is, throw an exception.  If any particular application considers any particular missing setting to be an exceptional case, that application can examine for an empty response and itself throw an exception.  Either way, there's no need for a separate method.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO having two methods to do precisely the same operation indicates that you as the API designer did not complete the job of 'designing' your API.  Choose one way or another, publicize it via the API (javadocs) and then the consumers will be consistent in their usage (one way or the other).